Correcting sampling bias (looking for data science or statistical approach)?
Lets say I am looking at a sample of students and their grades achieved across 5 subjects. 90% of my sample is biased towards worst performing students and 10% of my sample is random.
What is a simple method I could use to correct for bias in the sample, to approximate what the unbiased population of grades achieved might look like?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
